# How to use gradle to create a MANIFEST.MF file for a servlet?

Tags: java, gradle, servlets, war, manifest.mf

How do I use `gradle` to [create a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/4531180) deployable `WAR` file with, in particular, a correct `MANIFEST.MF` file?

the resulting `WAR` file:

```
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ ls
hello_jsp.war
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ jar xf hello_jsp.war 
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ tree
.
├── hello_jsp.war
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   └── servlets
    │       └── NewServlet.class
    └── lib
        ├── checker-qual-2.11.1.jar
        ├── commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
        ├── error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar
        ├── failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
        ├── guava-29.0-jre.jar
        ├── j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
        ├── jsr305-3.0.2.jar
        └── listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar

5 directories, 11 files
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly libs]$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0

[nsaunders@rolly libs]$
```

However, as above, the `MANIFEST.MF` is actually blank.

sample servlet:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

build file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'war'
//    id 'org.gretty'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    // Use TestNG framework, also requires calling test.useTestNG() below
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.2.0'


    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0' 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
   //  providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'

    
    

}

test {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}
```

Probably just needs an addition for the `MANIFEST.MF` file?

tree for the project:

```
hello_jsp/
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── servlets
                └── NewServlet.java

6 directories, 8 files
```

It's just a very basic hello-world web app for servlets and JSP's.

Answer (score 3):

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:jar_manifest

there are options to externalise the template as well.

applies to WARs as well

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": archiveVersion)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I ensure that `build` depends on the `jar` task above?